# How to run Coded UI Test thought TFS CI without active remote session?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, continuous-integration, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I experienced a problem with launching Coded UI Tests using Team Foundation Server (TFS) Continuous Integration (CI) without a remote session. I have followed all of the recommendations mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293551.aspx but this still requires an active remote session. The recommendation was to set up a test agent and build service in interactive mode.

Are there any workarounds for running a Coded UI Test remotely?

P.S. We have Windows 7 on our test machine.

Any help will do :)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't quite follow your question, but I had a problem that I think is something similar:

When running Coded UI Tests remotely, the machine can't be locked or have an active screensaver.  If you are running a virtual machine, such as on Hyper-V, and you connect to it using Remote Desktop Connection, closing that connection will lock the screen.

In my case, we were using Hyper-V so I connected using Hyper-V client, and then closed that window.  This doesn't lock the screen.

Source: Personal experience

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your problem. I think you mean you want to set up your test agent to run as 'Interactive process' so it can run tests that interact with the desktop (CoudeUi Tests). If this is the problem you are facing then check the following link:

- [How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests that Interact with the Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx)

Comment: Nop, i know how to set test agents into "interactive process", but when i query CI built my test fails because they need active remote control.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your issue. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193713/running-coded-ui-test-remotely

Comment: So i should use third party tools for solving this issue?

Comment: I am not sure. We are running our CodedUi Tests by MTM and we never faced that problem. In the link I gave in my answer there a lot of `Important`, `Caution` ... referring to the account that is running the service. Maybe is one of these notes that you have missed.

Comment: Ok i'll check, anyway thnx a lot:)