# Add items to the ROT( Running Objects Table)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins, running-object-table, vba

I know how to use *****.GetActiveObject(ProgId), however the problem is that several of the Applications I use this code line on are not added to the ROT, even if they are already open, I get an HRESULT Error. However If I click on another Application and then return to the original Application, the code line works just fine.

The reason I am leaving this so vague, is because this is a problem I am having across 10+ applications.

The reason for me not posting code is because I do not believe this problem to be code based, rather I believe this problem to be due to a simple lack of understanding on my part.

One of the Most Important Programs I am having this issue with is "Microsoft Excel".
All I want to do is be able to start the user at a specific cell.

I have looked all over for a decent explanation of how to use the *****.GetActiveObject(ProgId) in Excel, however, there does not seem to be any reasonable answers. The Program may be written in c#, however, if it is simpler in visual basic that is not a problem

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828175/exception-from-hresult-0x800401e3-mk-e-unavailable-workarounds) discuss some of the ways you can work around this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126

> COM servers are expected to register themselves in Running Object
>   Table after startup. Office programs register themselves when they
>   lose focus. If a program tries to attach to a running instance before
>   the program loses focus, you may receive an error message. For
>   additional information about how to work around this problem, click
>   the article number below to view the article in the Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base: [316125](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316125/EN-US) PRB: Visual C# .NET Error Attaching to Running
>   Instance of Office Application
>
> Using code, you can change focus from the Office application to your
>   own application (or to some other application) to allow it to register
>   itself in the ROT. Additionally, if your code is starting the
>   executable (.exe) file for the Office application, you may need to
>   wait for the Office application to finish loading before you attempt
>   to attach to the running instance.

Ensure another window is activated before attempting to connect. As shown in the example, you can use [`Form.Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) to focus your own form, thus causing the Office app to lose focus.

Comment: ok, that makes it much clearer, every other explanation I saw was not as clear, nor did they provide such a relatively simple answer., once again, thank you