# IRunningObjectTable::Register throws E_INVALIDARG while registering a class object

Tags: python, c++, mfc, com, comtypes

I'm trying to register a COM class object, which represents the application I want to automate, to the Running Object Table (ROT). However, the returned HRESULT is `E_INVALIDARG`, though all the supplied arguments match the [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irunningobjecttable-register) types.

The application type is EXE and it's registered in the Windows Registry with a CLSID and its type there is LocalServer.

The reason of my attempt relates to a similarly asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444419/add-items-to-the-rot-running-objects-table).

I usually connect with some applications using the [comtypes](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/) package of python, most of them succeed with the call to `GetActiveObject()`. However, when calling `GetActiveObject()` with the CLSID of this application I get an error

> WindowsError: [Error -2147221021] Operation unavailable

The effective part of the code of the MFC Application is the following

```cpp
CoInitialize(NULL);

IMoniker *appmnk;
CLSID appclsid;
IUnknown* app_ptr = NULL; //in CoGetClassObject, the pointer to the exe application

DWORD dwrdptr;

IRunningObjectTable *rot; //fetch the pointer using GetRunningObjectTable
HRESULT hr;
HRESULT hr0;
HRESULT hr1;
HRESULT hr2;
HRESULT hr3;

hr0 = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("TheApp.Application.1"), &appclsid);
// "TheApp.Application.1" is a hypothetical ProgID
// In the actual code, it's replaced with the actual ProgID

if (SUCCEEDED(hr0))
{
    hr1 = CoGetClassObject(appclsid, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, NULL, IID_IUnknown, (void **)&app_ptr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr1))
    {
        hr2 = CreateItemMoniker(L"!", OLESTR("myappmnk"), &appmnk);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr2))
        {
            hr3 = GetRunningObjectTable(0, &rot);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr3))
            {
                hr = rot->Register(ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE, app_ptr, appmnk, &dwrdptr);
                rot->Release();
            }
            appmnk->Release();
        }
        app_ptr->Release();
    }
}

CoUninitialize();
```

The end result I'm seeking is to successfully register the application's COM object to ROT, in order to get a successful result from `GetActiveObject`.

Any help and any insight will be truly appreciated.

Comment: You are leaking all of the COM objects returned by `CoGetClassObject()`, `CreateItemMoniker()` and `GetRunningObjectTable()`. You need to call `Release()` on all of them *before* calling `CoUninitialize()`. Also, `app_ptr` needs to be declared as `IUnknown*` and typecasted to `void**` when passed to `CoGetClassObject()`, not declared as `void*` and typecasted to `IUnknown*` when passed to `Register()`

Comment: And you are not doing any error handling to make sure that `CLSIDFromProgID()`, `CoGetClassObject()`, CreateItemMoniker()` and `GetRunningObjectTable()` all succeed before calling `Register()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
I've edited the code to handle the leaks with `Release()` for every successful step ..  changed the declaration of `app_ptr` to `IUnknown*` and typecasted it to `void**` when passed to `CoGetClassObject()` .. However, the same E_INVALIDARG error arises.

Comment: at which step exactly? The `Register()`?

Comment: It's the last step .. 
`hr = rot->Register(ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE, app_ptr, appmnk, &dwrdptr);`.. 
The value of `hr` is E_INVALIDARG

Comment: Replacing `Register()` with `BindMoniker()` gives the same E_INVALIDARG error 
 .. the line is `hr2 = BindMoniker(appmnk, dwrdptr, IID_IUnknown, (void **)app_ptr);` .. I'm confused about this moniker & app pointer issue, can't find a clean way to connect the object to the moniker in order to enable `Register()` to succeed.