# com exception excel InteropServices.COMException - c#

Tags: c#, excel, com, comexception

I am receiving `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` when running the below method from `main()`

I want to get `true` and later access the sheet if excel is opened on system. I am making sure excel is opened and `sheet1` is there but I get `false` and the error above.

`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

```
         public static bool IsExcelOpened(string sheet1)
    {
        bool isOpened = true;
        Excel.Application exApp;
        exApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        try
        {
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
            xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)exApp.Workbooks.get_Item(sheet1);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            isOpened = false;
        }
        return isOpened;
    }
```

**EDIT:**  when I run VS2019 as admin , I received more infor on error

`Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is Visual Studio running in a [different context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/54385484/852806) to Excel.

I tried a slightly modified version of your code and it works just fine when running Visual Studio *NOT* as admin (same user as excel was opened with).

Might be worth checking you are using the right version of the interop dll also.

```
public bool IsExcelOpened()
        {
            bool isOpened = false;

            try
            {
                Excel.Application exApp;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
                exApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;
                if(exApp != null)
                {
                    xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)exApp.ActiveSheet;
                    isOpened = true;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return isOpened;
        }
```

Comment: This works. The only thing is that , I have to close `excel` process from task manager to get false.  When I ran excel as admin and ran my version of code the original error was gone but I received `'System.InvalidCastException'` . Do you have any idea why I received that. Is `xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)exApp.Workbooks.get_Item(sheet1);` wrong way ?

Comment: I don't think anything you have done is wrong. I perfer to use 'as' instead of direct casting, which then gives you the chance for null checking. Direct casting will throw an error if it's not happy. I couldn't get the get_Item to work, which is why I went for ActiveSheet. All microsoft applications can hang about in the background for a bit after closing which is a bit annoying. We didn't have a work around. We just added a 'Kill All Excels' which hasn't been used that often as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same issue, the main reason is Microsoft doesn't support the Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services).
So, I tried to manually register the excel to ROT (running object table) by using a shell command like
`Process.Start("Path to your excel file")`
before creating the `Marshal.GetActiveObject()`.