# Can I run Coded Ui Test on a minimized RDP window?

Tags: virtual-machine, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

I am running the Coded-UI test through command-line as scheduled task on a VM via RDP. I just found that when I tried to minimize the RDP window, the tests were halted. Is there anyway that I can run the tests without an open RDP windows or I can minimize the window?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Coded UI test remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193713/running-coded-ui-test-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't but you can have another window on TOP of your RDP wihtout any problems.